# 301 or noindex or both

Tags: 301-redirect, noindex

I have lots of categories but I use different pages as landing page for each categories and in pages I just load the contents of each category that I need (I cant delete my categories)
what is best solution for categories ?

- no index
- 301 redirect
- or both ?!

Certainly when google see a 301 redirect cant check HTML codes, is true? then it is not important that page had an Noindex robots tag)
thanks

Comment: That's true when Google see 301/404 status, it doesn't crawl that page.

Comment: Using a 301 redirect for the categories will effectively delete them.   Can you not use a 301 redirect because of that?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is slightly confusing.

If you are trying to show a code only when Google visits, and a different one for your visitors, that called cloaking, and it's frowned upon by Google, which might get you penalized.

If what you want is not to allow Googlebot (or any other bot for that matter) to scan and index your category pages (usually this is done to prevent duplication), then a super simple and highly recommended approach is to put the directives on your **robots.txt** file:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /category/*
```